# Библиотека GLFW в C++ проекте в QT Creator

Tags: c++, qtcreator, cmake, glfw

Я пытаюсь создать C++ проект с использованием библиотеки GLFW. В качестве IDE использую QT Creator, система сборки - CMake, ОС - Windows.

Заголовочные файлы находятся в папке D:\opengl\include

Библиотека GLWF - D:\opengl\libs\libglfw3.a

С++ код:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
   glfwInit();
   return 0;
}
```

Файл CMakeLists.txt в корне проекта:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
include_directories("D:/opengl/include/" "D:/opengl/libs/")
add_library(GLFW STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET GLFW PROPERTY
             IMPORTED_LOCATION D:/opengl/include/libs/libglfw3.a)
target_link_libraries(test GLFW)
```

Сейчас при подготовке проекта выдаётся ошибка

> :-1: ошибка: cannot find -lglfw

Я находил темы с похожими проблемами, переписывал CMakeLists.txt разными способами, но ни один не сработал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно подключить библиотеку GLFW к моему проекту?

Comment: libglfw3.a - почему у Вас библиотека в WinOS имеет расширенее, характерное для linux?

Comment: Скачал по этой [ссылке](https://github-production-release-asset-2e65be.s3.amazonaws.com/9524997/04b8a61a-655d-11e6-9457-7a96314d9e35?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20171027%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20171027T161535Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=f02a9287a804b52f1f96012475208ce9c99b154805ff43a651df6bc8c462a99e&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=12003993&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dglfw-3.2.1.bin.WIN32.zip&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream) и там файлы с типичными для WinOS расширениями.

Comment: Пересобрал библиотеку GLFW с расширением .dll. Положил новую .dll библиотеку рядом со старой .a. Подкорректировал CMakeLists.txt. Теперь подготовка проекта проходит без ошибок, но при компиляции выдаётся:
>ninja: error: 'D:/opengl/include/libs/glfw3.dll', needed by 'test.exe', missing and no known rule to make it

Comment: Расшарьте Ваш CMake файл и дайте линк на него, пожалуйста.

Comment: Ааа...ну и линковаться нужно с .lib, а к исполняемому файлу подкладывать .dll - либо рядом, либо путь к директории с .dll добавить в $PATH.

Comment: http://rgho.st/private/84cDgtZ9g/d910d7d81ad5ace89a09ba4d4f0f49b9
Файл CMakeLists.txt
То есть нужны .lib и .dll одновременно? Как-то слишком, нет?

Comment: Сделайте, как описано в [этом](http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html#build_link_win32) мануале. На персе только Debian стоит, проверить сам не могу.